# node.js get Chinese characters from JSON file

Tags: json, node.js, character

i have a Json file where i have saved some Chinese text.
when i print it in my pdfkit project this is the result = [image]
the blue thext is write inside the code and works.
the red is get by a Json file and don't works (if i change the json file into normal characters works)

Comment: Are you missing encoding ? some.toString('utf8') ? or utf16. Not sure. Check also that your input are utf compatible. BIG* character encoding is not good !

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have the same problem when using require to read the json file, I changed to use fs.readFile and works for me, check the code:

```
fs.readFile('./app/config/language-base.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        //var lang = JSON.parse(data.toString('utf8').replace(/^\uFEFF/, ''));
        var lang = JSON.parse(data);

        lang.languages.forEach(function(ln, i){
            var source = {};
            Object.keys(lang.source).forEach(function(word, i){
                gutil.log('Generating word ', gutil.colors.magenta(word), "for language ", gutil.colors.red(ln));
                source[word] = lang.source[word][ln];
                gutil.log('Current word ', gutil.colors.blue(source[word]));
            });

            var source = JSON.stringify(source);
            var path = './app/locales/'+ln+".json";
            fs.writeFileSync(path, source, 'utf8');

        });

    });
```

Hope this help you!!

Answer (score 0):

I've just encounter this (or similar) problem when using fs to read a JSON file that contains the Chinese bible text. The code I had was:

```
var bible = fs.readFileSync('./files/bible.json', 'utf8');
var jsonBible = JSON.parse(bible);
```

JSON was not able to parse the content read from the file. The error message was:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0

I then tried to change 'utf8' to 'utf16le'. The error message then changed to:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0

It turned out there was some unprintable character at the end of the file that caused problem for JSON to parse the file content. Using the trim() method removed that character and JSON was then able to parse the file. So the final working code is:

```
var bible = fs.readFileSync('./files/bible.json', 'utf16le').trim();
var jsonBible = JSON.parse(bible);
```